# Can Google Form send email automatically based on entered field?

Tags: google-forms, notifications, automation

I would like to use Google Form as a help desk, hoping to find a script that can send email of the submitted form responses to different people depending on their option in one of the question?

i.e. If user fill in the form and chose A, Mr X will get an email notification with the copy of the form response.
If user fill in the form and chose B, Mrs Y will get an email notification with the copy of the form response.
Thank you in advance!